# Filtered DE Bug in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

We used a filtered DE as an entry source in Journey Builder.

- The filtered DE filtered 93,733 contacts.
- After the journey activation and the scheduled start, you can see in the screenshot there are 11,412,694 contacts entering the journey.

Has anyone experienced this bug before and can you think of any scenario how this might have happened? We have a CASE with SF support opened and we still don't have any explanation. Thank you.

[image: Filtered DE Bug in JB]

Comment: Juraj, the bottom of the screendump's clipped, so I can't see the schedule section. Is this journey running on a recurring schedule from an Automation? Has the Automation run more than once and refreshed the Filtered DE? If so, a Filtered DE is basically truncated when refreshed and then all records added back into the table, so every contact is seen as newly added, even if they were present before the refresh. Could this be your problem?

Comment: Hi @Macca sorry for replying with delay. The schedule is to start in the future and never to repeat (= run once). We had this escalated with SF support.

SF support comment:
"If you open the Marketing Cloud within multiple browser tabs simultaneously you may experience duplication in data discrepancy, scheduling, object creation, or other unpredictable behaviors such as pages not loading as expected during the schedule"

Comment: SF support resolution:

"Opening up multiple tabs in the Marketing Cloud in the same session is to be avoided.
As a best practice, only open the Marketing Cloud within one browser tab at a time. This encompasses all applications contained in the Marketing Cloud."